# can we create a quiz in python using only functions and also keep track of scores

Tags: python

I wanted to create a function which can keep track of the scores from each of the questions and then use it in another function which returns the final result to the user. I have no idea of how to do so.

```
# Function for question 1
def ask_question_one(difficulty):
      score = 0
      print("What is the capital city of Canada?")
      answer = input()
      if difficulty <= 3:
            if answer == "Ottawa" or answer == "ottawa":
                  score = score + 10
                  print("Your score is:", score)
            else:
                  print(score)
      elif difficulty > 3 and difficulty <= 7:
            if answer == "Ottawa" or answer == "ottawa":
                  score = score + 30
                  print ("your score is:", score)
            else:
                  print("You have given an incorrect answer. You lose 5 points.")
                  score = score - 5
                  print("Your score is:", score)
      else:
            count = 1
            while count < 3:
                  answer = input()
                  if answer != "Ottawa" or answer != "ottawa":
                        score = score - 5
                        print("Your score is:", score)
                            
            score = score + 50
            print("Your score after two tries is:", score)
                                                                       
def display_result(difficulty, score):
   if difficulty <= 3 and score > 30:
      print("Your difficulty level is", str(difficulty) + " and your score is", str(score))


# Top-level code.
set_difficulty = int(input("Please enter a difficuty level between 1 and 10: "))  
if set_difficulty == "":
     print("You did not enter a difficulty level. Try again! Exiting quiz.")
     exit()
elif set_difficulty == 0:
      print("0(zero) is not a valid difficulty. Exiting quiz.")
      exit()
elif set_difficulty > 10:
      print("Select a difficulty level less than 10.")
      exit()
else:
    print("....Let's begin the quiz....")

ask_question_one(set_difficulty)
```

here is what i have done so far

Comment: Please show us some effort...and code!

Comment: I have provided a sample code for the program i asked please check it out

Comment: And what the actual problem with that code?

Comment: in the display_result function i have a parameter for score but i am not sure how to call another function which will do the scoring for me

Answer (score -1):

Please explain the comment correctly. Then maybe I can answer (I am putting this here because I don't have enough reputation for posting comments :'( ).